# Confused with this HashMap algorithm interview question

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable

i'm studying interview questions and came across this question thats really confusing me. I know how to do the basic O(n^2) solution but the HashTable O(n) is not making any sense.

```
static void printpairs(int arr[],int sum) 
{        
    HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) 
    { 
        int temp = sum-arr[i]; 

        // checking for condition 
        if (temp>=0 && s.contains(temp)) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Pair with given sum " + 
                                sum + " is (" + arr[i] + 
                                ", "+temp+")"); 
        } 
        s.add(arr[i]); 
    } 
}
```

The part that is confusing me is the part where its checking condition.  it does s.contains(temp) when nothing is put into the hashtable. So how can it contain sum - i?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/

Comment: There is a loop. From the second interation onwards, something will have been put into the hashset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a `HashSet`, not a hash table.

Second of all, `s.add(arr[i])` adds elements to the `HashSet`, therefore `s.contains(temp)` may return `true`.

For example, suppose you are looking for a pair having the sum 8.

- If the first element of the array is `1`, you don't find `8-1` in the `Set`, but you add `1` to the `Set`.
- Then, if the second element of the array is `7`, you find `8-7` in the `Set` (since you added `1` to the `Set` in the previous iteration).

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I thought A[i] was added inside the loop.